# Sensors to detect inside liquids temperature and percentage of alcohol

Tags: sensor, raspberry-pi

I would like to measure and study the correlation between temperature and percentage of alcohol inside a bin with fermenting beer, what type of sensor do I need.

I was planning to plug this sensors to a raspberry pi, but in case not compatible I could try to plug them to a pic18 or pic16, which I worked with some time ago. However if compatible with raspberry pi, even better.

Thanks for your feedback.

Comment: A better question would be to ask what type of sensors you could use, or what things to consider when choosing the apprpriate sensors.  As you've written, this is a request for a part recommendation.  Those are off topic here, and will get your question closed.  I've already voted to close.  If 4 others agree before you change, then it will be closed.

Comment: You might be looking for an ethanol sensor that can help you figure out the percentage of alcohol per volume. As far as temperature, you'll have to get something separate. Interesting that you want to measure the alcoholic content of something. The bottle on the alcoholic beverage is legally obligated to tell you how much per volume there is. The only reason why I can imagine that you need to do this is if you're hand brewing and fermenting your own alcohol.

Comment: @KingDuken Thanks for the information. Yes I am fermenting my own beer, and I would like how temperature modify the percentage of alcohol. I will look for ethanol sensor.

Comment: @JRE actually what I was looking is for an ethanol sensor as KingDuken pointed out, and what I would like to know recommendations of brands which are compatible with raspberry pi

Comment: "*I would like to know recommendations of brands*" is going to get your question closed. See [On-Topic](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You actually measure the specifc gravity of the wort, not alcohol. A hydrometer (or refractometer) is used.

As sugar converts to alcohol, SG falls. this is predictive. Alcohol is set by sugar content not temperature. Temperature just affects speed of the fermenation (and taste), not the final alcohol.

An interesting alternative would be measure the [CO2 outgassing](https://lifefermented.wordpress.com/2014/01/22/how-much-co2-is-produced-from-brewing/). e.g. count bubbles through the airlock.
If you look at those graphs you see that 20l of wort will loose 2kg of CO2, so weighing it can also work.

If you want relative fermentation action, then counting bubbles through the airlock U would be the way to go. You could use capacitive sensing, optical or just fine stainless wires through the U of a plastic airlock.

If you use a hydrometer start and finish and calculate the alcohol, then you could later calibrate each bubble to alcohol.

Comment: thanks for the explanation. Do you know any trustful company which sells that sort of sensors??

Comment: a hygrometer from your brewshop. You do understand that alcohol of your beer is set by sugar content not temperature. Temperature just affects speed of the fermenation (and taste), not the final alcohol.

Comment: Yes. I knew that. The thing is I dont have a place with stable temperature, so I was planning to measure how fast the fermentation takes place depending on the season and temperature.

Comment: @HenryCrun hydrometer and hygrometer are two different things,...

Comment: So having a closed vessel with airlock would allow either/both measuring CO2 bubbling or weighing, which would show you the fermentation progress. Counting CO2 bubbles would give nice fast resolution. In my experience (and our houses don't have central heating), when I added a temperature controlled heater, brewing became reliable. No more hung fermentations.